# write System.out to file with log4j2

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

Is it possible to write the System.out (OutputStream) directly to a log file like in the "old" log4j?

I only find solutions for log4j, not log4j2

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

It is quite easy using `log4j2-iostreams` module. Let's say we want to send all messages from `System.out` to a logger with name `system.out` with log level `INFO`:

```
System.setOut(
        IoBuilder.forLogger(LogManager.getLogger("system.out"))
                .setLevel(Level.INFO)
                .buildPrintStream()
);
System.out.println("Lorem ipsum");
```

with the following `log4j2.properties`

```
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d [%p] %c - %m%n

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

we should see the following output in the console:

```
2017-10-28 12:38:22,623 [INFO] system.out - Lorem ipsum
```

Comment: I struggled with maven dependency and includes. So Here they are.
Maven dependency for this is:
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-iostreams</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>`.
Include block:
`import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.io.IoBuilder;`

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming 2.1 release contains a new log4j-iostreams module which can do this and more. Should be out soon.

If you're in a hurry you can check out the latest source from master and build the 2.1 snapshot.

Comment: just downloaded log4j2-5, and still can't figure out how to send system.out to file