# Log runtime exceptions in file log4j2

Tags: java, exception, log4j2

I was reading the log4j2 documentation and I've made some code with that library, but I can't find a solution to log the runtime exceptions, like null pointers, timeouts or something like that in a file, I just see those exceptions in the console. I've read about this, and I see that I can achieve that with an aspect but my question is: There is a way to log those exceptions in a file through XML configuration?

EDIT:

I have a log4j2 configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="5">
    <Appenders>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%r %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:sss} %c %L %M %sn [%t] %-5p %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>

        <File name="testingFile" fileName="testLog4j.log" append="true" ignoreExceptions="false" immediateFlush="true">

            <!--Layout type="PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>%r %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:sss} %c %L %M %sn [%t] %-5p %msg%n</Pattern>
            </Layout-->
            <PatternLayout alwaysWriteExceptions="false">
                <Pattern>"%-5p [%t] %logger - %msg%ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>

        </File>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" level="info"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="testingFile" level="error"/>
        </Root>



        <!--Logger name="com.example" level="error" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="testingFile" />
        </Logger-->
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

---

And I have the following class:

```
public class Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Application.class.getName());

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        while(true){
            //logger.debug("test");
            logger.trace("trace");
            logger.debug("debug");
            logger.info("test");
            logger.warn("test");
            logger.error("test");
            logger.fatal("test");
            logger.error("test");
            String s = null;
            s.substring(0);
        }
    }
```

When you reach the line `s.substring(0)` you get a `NullPointerException`, this exception is logged in the console and not in the File Appender, and I want to log this kinds of exceptions in my file appender.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [write System.out to file with log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318295/write-system-out-to-file-with-log4j2)

Comment: Hi, I just edited my question to clarify what I want to do.

Comment: Edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

### Log4j2 file appender:

Did you define a `Log4j2` [File appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)?

So, to log to a file won't require any changes to your Java code.  Maybe logging to the console can work without it, but I have a `log4j2.xml` file in my project root that defines how `Log4j2` should log.

Here is my current version with a [Console appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender) and a [File appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender) defined:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status="WARN">
        <Appenders>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            </Console>
            <File name="File" fileName="logs/app.log">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            </File>
        </Appenders>
        <Loggers>
            <Root level="TRACE">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
                <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
            </Root>
        </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

There might be other ways to achieve the same result.  Have a look at the [Logj42 Configuration page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

If you want, have a look at the other types of appenders available [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html).  If you're not happy with how the log messages display you can read up on [Pattern layouts](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout).

---

### Logging exceptions:

You asked about logging errors and seem to successfully be able to log general log statements.

You just need to wrap your code in a [try-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

For example:

```java
try {
    logger.info("Hello world");

    // I want to test my exception handling
    throw new RuntimeException("Triggering an error");
} catch (Exception e) {
    String errorMessage = "An error has occurred";
    logger.error(errorMessage, e);
    throw new RuntimeException(errorMessage, e);
}
```

Note that I catch an [Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) and throw a [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).  An `Exception` is a checked exception - so calling code will need to catch it, while `RuntimeException` (a subclass of `Exception`) is an unchecked exception.  So by throwing the `RuntimeException` I'm sort of insinuating that something totally unexpected happened and that the calling code won't know how to deal with it - so they don't need to `catch` it, and since its an unchecked exception they won't have to.

So in the `catch` clause you can, depending on your requirements, throw an `Exception`, or a `RuntimeException`, or your own custom exception which can be either a checked exception (a subclass of `Exception`), or an unchecked exception (a subclass of `RuntimeException`).

If you don't throw your `Exception` from the `catch` clause the code will continue executing subsequent to the `catch` clause which is most likely not what you want.

I see your code is inside a `public static void main(String args[])` method.  So maybe you don't have to throw the `Exception` from the `catch` clause as program execution will in any case stop subsequent to the `catch` clause if the `catch` clause is at the end of the method.  Maybe Java will print something on the console if you throw something out of that method - but it won't be caught and logged by `Log4j2`.

---

### Logging with aspects:

I see you can log using aspects.  See for example [here](https://learnjava-soa.blogspot.com/2015/06/aspectj-example-with-log4j2.html).  That said, I will just try and get everything working with `try-catch`.  I haven't had to use aspects for logging and it feels like its a bit of work for a benefit that isn't too clear so I can't unfortunately help with that.

Hope the rest of my answer was useful :)

Comment: Hi there, yea I have that file but I've edited my question to clarify what I want to do.

Comment: Edited my answer :)

Comment: @NSduToit , It is always not required to throw the exception...why not better log it somewhere at that right moment??

Comment: I do log it...?  I'm trying to teach him about not swallowing exceptions - catching them and then erroneously letting the program just continue executing.

Comment: Hi, in my example the `NullPointerException` is logged in the console without catching the exception. Maybe the people of apache consider that these cases are not relevant in production environments.

Comment: Are you sure its `log4j2` doing the logging of your `NullPointerException`?  Maybe its Java doing some logging because the `public static void main` method exited with an `Exception` and the Java process was ended.  Does the logging of the `NullPointerException` have the same format as your other `log4j2` logging statements?

Comment: Because an `Exception` won't be logged by `log4j2` if you don't pass it to your `logger` class.

Answer (score 0):

Checked all your XML configurations and they seem ok. The only thing that you need to get runtime exceptions logged in the file is:

```
  private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Log4j2Example.class);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      String s = null;
      s.substring(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("RunTime Exception: " + e, e);
    }
  }
```

The `toString` of Exception is inherited from `Throwable` where it prints the Exception class name and the message. This gets added to the string "**RunTime Exception:** " to form one string that is getting printed.

So you need to pass the exception to the `logger.error` as an argument.

```
logger.error("RunTime Exception: " + e, e);
```

Comment: In this case you have to catch the exception and pass the argument to the logger, I did this for catched exceptions, but I read that catch runtime exceptions is considered a bad practice. I guess there is no way to log runtime exceptions to a file without using the logger object with log4j2.

Comment: Catch runtime exceptions are not bad, often we came across this in enterprise solutions.